# Bootstrap Accordion collapse with Ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, erb

Collapse is only working on the first button, and I know it's because only the first div id is being set for all buttons. How do I iterate and make new div id's for each element when using hash.each?

Here's my erb:

```
<% @contacts.each do |category, hash| %>
<div class="panel-group" id=accordion">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
   <h3 class="panel-title"><%= category %></h3>
   </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
 <ul class="list-group">
  <% hash.each do |contact| %>
    <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#demo"><%= contact['name'] %></button>
    <div id="demo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"><%= contact['email'] %></br><%= contact['ext'] %>
        </div>
    </div>
   </li>
<% end %>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the corresponding code from my .rb:

```
get '/contact' do
contact = Contacts.new
@contacts = contact.getContacts
@contacts.each { |s| puts "get /contact found contact #{s.last.first['name']}" }
erb :contact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<% hash.each_with_index do |contact, index| %>
    <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse<%= index %>"><%= contact['name'] %></button>
    <div id="collapse<%= index %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"><%= contact['email'] %></br><%= contact['ext'] %>
        </div>
    </div>
   </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Getting a syntax error - unrecognized expression on #collapse#{index}

Comment: Ran your changes and still getting a syntax error, it doesn't like `data-target="#collapse#{index}"`

Comment: updated my answer, it should be target=`#collapse<%= index %>` and id=`collapse<%= index %>`

Comment: Running into another issue with indexing the divs: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983887/bootstrap-accordion-collapse-not-indexing-divs-correctly)