# Bootstrap Accordion Collapse not indexing divs correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

When trying to index divs so that the accordion buttons will collapse correctly, it's indexing every first contact in each category in my json file as 0 instead of indexing every contact no matter the category consecutively.

Here's my erb file:

```
<% @contacts.each do |category, hash| %>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title"><%= category %></h3>
  </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <% hash.each_with_index do |contact, index| %>
        <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse<%= index %>"><%= contact['name'] %><%= index %></button>
          <div id="collapse<%= index %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <%= contact['email'] %></br><%= contact['ext'] %>
          </div>
        </li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

json file: (It's indexing the first name in each group i.e. "Manager, Team Lead" as 0. I want Rob = 0, Terry = 1, Ben = 3, and so on.

```
{
    "Manager":[
    {
      "name": "Rob",
      "email": "Rob@com",
      "ext": "ext:"
    }
  ],
  "Team Lead":[
    {
      "name": "Terry",
      "email": "Terry@com",
      "ext": "ext"
    }
    ],
  "Unix Admins":[
      {
        "name": "Ben",
        "email": "Benjamin@com",
        "ext": "ext"
      },
      {
        "name": "Prashant",
        "email": "Prashant@com",
        "ext": "ext"
      },
      {
        "name": "Harshil
        "email": "Harshil@com",
        "ext": "ext"
      },
      {
        "name": "Laxmikanth",
        "email": "Laxmikanth@com",
        "ext": "ext"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mary",
        "email": "Mary@com",
        "ext": "ext"
      }
    ],
    "On-Call Contact":[
      {
        "name": "SYSTEM ADMIN UNIX",
        "email": "Unix@com",
        "ext": "ext"
      }
    ]
}
```

.rb file:

```
get '/contact' do
    contact = Contacts.new
    @contacts = contact.getContacts
    @contacts.each { |s| puts "get /contact found contact #{s.last.first['name']}" }
    erb :contact
```

Comment: what is the full name of this .rb file? I didn't understand it

Comment: The file is named app.rb. The erb file above is contact.erb. Is that what you're asking for?